# Remove carriage return line feed from a line that match regex pattern with awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have the following situation where I would like to remove the carriage return line feed from a line where the next line starts with a certain pattern.
In the case below the "next line" starts with "." with x amount of spaces in front of the "."
 
I would like to remove the carriage return line feed at the end of the previous line, along with the spaces in front of the "."

```
Query.FieldByName('dataField')
        .AsString;
```

After applying the awk script the code should look like this

```
Query.FieldByName('dataField').AsString;
```

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this:

```
awk '/^\s*\./{sub(/^\s*/,"");printf "%s",$0;next}
             {printf "%s%s",(NR==1?"":RS),$0}END{print ""} ' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  cat f
foo
.bar
  .bar2
xyz
                .abc

kent$  awk '/^\s*\./{sub(/^\s*/,"");printf "%s",$0;next}{printf "%s%s",(NR==1?"":RS),$0}END{print ""} ' f
foo.bar.bar2
xyz.abc
```